# Updating javafx UI using task without using Platform.RunLater

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, pane

I want to update my javafx UI but I Don't want to use Platform.RunLater but when i want to update my Pane on :

```
Pane.getChildren().add(listview);
```

I get java.lang.illegalStateException : not on java fx application thread;current thread

Comment: All UI activity should be run on a special thread, `runLater` is an easiest way to achieve that. Why don't you want to use `Platform.RunLater`?

Comment: because as I have read about it's not recommeneded for big and long tasks

Comment: @navidmahdian adding listView into a pane isn't a big task.

Comment: its just a short example of it

Comment: i'm making a client server which can send text and images.when sending images the program stops

Comment: @navidmahdian You're only supposed to put the UI update in `Platform.runLater(...)`. The long-running code just goes in the `call` method, but not in `Platform.runLater(..)`. Or, probably better, use an `onSucceeded(...)` handler on the `Task`. It's really impossible to answer your question unless you post some sample code showing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Task itself uses `Platform.runLater` for updates. If you are afraid of posting too many runables using `Platform.runLater` simply use Runables that can do multiple updates at once & synchronize (e.g. something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40678129/2991525)

Answer (score 1):

You must update the UI elements on the UI thread using `Platform.runLater()`.

If you have a long-running task, then perform the task first, and the update the UI with the results of the task.

```
Object taskResult = GetLongRunningTaskResult();
Platform.runLater(() -> Pane.getChildren().add(taskResult));
```